# Hive: column type of Decimal(12,9) throws NullPointerException with JSONSerDe

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I have a an external table that points to json data. I am using serde `org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe`.
I have created a view on top of this external table using DDL:

```
CREATE VIEW `my_table` AS SELECT
a.col1,
a.col2,
...
...
a.longitude,
a.latitude
FROM
(SELECT
mytable.body.col1,
mytable.body.col2,
....
..
mytable.body.longitude,
mytable.body.latidute,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY mytable.body.col1, mytable.body.col1 ORDER BY mytable.body.col3 DESC )
AS rownum FROM mydb.myExtTable) AS a where a.rownum=1
```

When I am doing a `SELECT * FROM mytable` it is giving me a `NullPointerException`:

```
Vertex failed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1529530522022_75616_22_01, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1529530522022_75616_22_01_000000, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) [Error getting row data with exception java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryHiveDecimal.init(LazyBinaryHiveDecimal.java:47)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryStruct.uncheckedGetField(LazyBinaryStruct.java:267)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryStruct.getField(LazyBinaryStruct.java:204)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.objectinspector.LazyBinaryStructObjectInspector.getStructFieldData(LazyBinaryStructObjectInspector.java:64)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:354)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:354)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:354)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:198)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:184)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource$GroupIterator.next(ReduceRecordSource.java:347)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource.pushRecord(ReduceRecordSource.java:274)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordProcessor.run(ReduceRecordProcessor.java:266)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:150)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:139)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:347)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:194)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:181)
        at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 ]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:173)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:139)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:347)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:194)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:181)
        at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have just 2 records as JSON.
The two JSON are like:

```
{"header": {"header1":"value1", "header2": "value2"}, "body": {"col1": "col1 value", "col2": "col2 value",.... "latitude": 39.921302, "longitude": -74.879928}}
{"header": {"header1":"value1", "header2": "value2"}, "body": {"col1": "col1 value", "col2": "col2 value",.... "latitude": 43658734.438, "longitude": 3453.3453}}
```

The weird part is when I run a `SELECT` on my VIEW using only 1 record it fetches me correctly, but running it for both records together, it gives me Exception.

When I am removing the `"latitude": 43658734.438, "longitude": 3453.3453` values from JSON data(from the 2nd record), things are running fine again.
The columns `longitude` and `latitude` are of type `decimal(12,9)`.
As I suspect, is there any issue with the column value ?
But if the values are posing issue while running both records together, why are they running fine individually (Note: when running the 2nd record indivdually , however these 2 column values for this record is getting replaced by `NULL`).
What could be the issue ?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the definition https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_decimal.html

`decimal(12,9)` means 12 digits with 9 digits after the decimal point, so 3 digits before. looks like you need at least `decimal(14,6)` here

Comment: Thanks Harold. That was helpful. For `"latitude": 43658734.438` i need to make it decimal(18,9)